# Explanation for "south pole" brainteaser (height of a spherical cap from the radius of the base only?)

Tags: geometry

Question #1 from Gardner's "My Best Mathematical and Logic Puzzles" is a classic brainteaser: where on the globe, other than the north pole, can someone walk a mile south, a mile east, a mile north, and find himself back at his original location?

I understand the solution (any point on circle A, where circle A is one mile north of circle B, where circle B has a circumference of one mile).

But I don't understand how Gardner can claim that circle B is ~$\frac{1}{2\pi}$ miles north of the south pole (ignoring curvature).  Can someone explain the geometry behind this?  I understand circle B will have a radius of $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ miles (given the circumference of 1 mile) but how does this translate to the circle B being ~$\frac{1}{2\pi}$ miles from the south pole?

Comment: $\sin(\alpha)\approx \alpha$ for small $\alpha$.  Note that $\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+O(x^9)$

Comment: The Earth is big, The flat-earth approximation works fine at that sort of scale, despite the sharply curving eastward path, which - like other eastward trajectories - stays a constant distance from both poles.